# GeoNetwork WPS harvesting

Tags: wps, geonetwork, iso-19139, catalog-service, iso-19119

I'm doing some testing of GeoNetwork and trying to harvest some OGC services to populate the catalogue with datasets and processing tools. Following the GeoNetwork documentation, this works well for WFS data with a separate metadata entry created for each data set (GeoServer) - I specify the "Create record for each layer only using GetCapabilities information" option to ensure separate entries.

However, when trying to harvest a WPS (located on my local machine) the harvester won't create individual entries for each of the process algorithms / operations - even if I select the "Create record for each layer " option. Instead it creates one record with multiple  tags for each of the algorithms.

Is it possible to harvest a WPS and generate registration for each process within GeoNetwork?

I'm wondering if this might be a limitation to using ISO 19139 to record separate processes. Perhaps I should only be using it to register the whole service enpoint?